# How to create criteria for date specific query in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

How to create criteria in hibernate for following query :

```
select * from xmppserveripinfo where update_dt > (select DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 MINUTE))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example demonstrates how it works:

```
public List<XmppServerIpInfo > find(final int intervalInMinutes) {
    return getHibernateTemplate().execute(new HibernateCallback<List<XmppServerIpInfo>>() {

        public List<XmppServerIpInfo> doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
            Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(XmppServerIpInfo.class);
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -intervalInMinutes);
            crit.add(Restrictions.ge("updateTime", cal.getTime()));
            crit.addOrder(Order.asc("updateTime"));
            return crit.list();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. that worked for me. However, the cal object was returning string value so i had to convert it to the date object for proper comparison with the values in my database.